# gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found while installing Varnish

Tags: 17.04

I am trying to install Varnish for ubuntu 17.04

While running this command:

```
sudo curl http://repo.varnish-cache.org/debian/GPG-key.txt | sudo apt-key add -
```

I got an error like this

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because that page does not contain valid GPG data. Please visit the [link you provided](http://repo.varnish-cache.org/debian/GPG-key.txt) in a browser. You'll see a text explaining that the site is discontinued:

> repo.varnish-cache.org is no more.
>
> [The project homepage](http://varnish-cache.org/releases/) has full details about where to obtain releases, packages etc.

In general, when you get an error like this trying to feed web content into another tool from the command line, it's a good idea to visit the web resource, and have a manual look at the content. Does it look like what one should expect, or does it show some error message?